# Cannot get Foundation's Abide to work with Html Helper form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zurb-foundation

I updated my ASP.NET MVC project to include form validation - Abide (foundation.abide.js), but when I go to include data-abide in the form, it throws up an error. I added it to a foundation folder that is part of a script bundle which is referenced on my layout view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateJourney", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "custom", id="postJourneyForm", name="postJourneyForm", data-abide}))
```

Can someone explain what I am missing? Is it due to the fact that I only added the javascript file and nothing else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using MVC4 `data_abide = ""` works, creating an attribute without a value.

Applying this into your code looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateJourney", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "custom", id="postJourneyForm", name="postJourneyForm", data_abide=""}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Change part of your code
from

```
data-abide
```

to

```
data_abide
```